# How to use string as a delimiter in getline() function in c++

Tags: c++

I have structure member which takes the value of delimiter from XML.And I want use that structure member as delimiter . But as `getline()` function take delimiter as char only so my I'm stuck over there.

`istream& getline (istream& is, string& str, char delim)`

I have done following thing in my code:-

```
string ABC = struct.delimiter;    // Here struct.delimiter is takes value of
                                     d delimiter from XML delimiter = '='
```

and I want use as

```
getline(string1,string2, ABC);
```

Is it possible?
or 
Is there another way to do it?

Comment: Is `ABC` guaranteed to contain a single character?

Comment: ABC will contain delimiter for e.g '=' and it is act like a string not a character so i'm not able to use it. Is there another function to so the same thing except getline().

Comment: Right but will it always be a single character or can it be something like `" = "`, `":="`, `"some large delimiter"`, etc?

Comment: No is it only one character

Comment: @Kevin suppose I didn't have single character like `"\r\n"` as  a delimiter instead of `'='`? then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot achieve this with a getLine, the best way I know of to do this would be to get your line, store it in a string and use the find() function to find your delimiters.

```
string string; // Your line
string ABC = struct.delimiter; // Delimited
getline(input, string); // Get line from stream - Thx Kevin
string subStr = str.substr(0, str.find(ABC)); // this will get you the first segment
```

From here on you can develop your loop to go over the read data and find all segments.

Comment: Why is the 3rd line declaring `getline`? Is it supposed to be `getline(is, str)`?

Comment: Haha you're right, I just copied his initial getLine, but the wrong one obviously, don't have an IDE here to test so I'm writing blind a bit.

Answer (score 0):

If `ABC` is guaranteed to be a single character in length you can use `ABC[0]` to get the first character out of the string:

```
getline(string1, string2, ABC[0]);
```

Or just make `ABC` a `char` to make that guarantee even more apparent.

```
char ABC = struct.delimiter; // (assuming struct.delimiter is also a char,
                             //  if not use srtuct.delimiter[0])
getline(string1, string2, ABC);
```

Comment: If I want to use delimiter as double character .Is it possible to use with getline? if it is then how? or any other STL function is there?

Comment: You can't use `getline` for that. TheMPC's answer might be a possible solution for you.